# How to simplify $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{e^{\sum_{i=0}^kx_{i}}}{\sum_{i=0}^k x_{i}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, logarithms, exponential-function

Is it possible to simplify
$$
S(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}  \frac{e^{\sum_{i=0}^kx_{i}}}{\sum_{i=0}^k x_{i}}
$$
A few observations:

- $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^k x_{i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(n+1-k)x_k$
- $ e^{\sum_{i=0}^kx_{i}}=\prod_{i=0}^k e^{x_i}$
- $S(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{\sum_{i=0}^kx_{i}-\log\left( \sum_{i=0}^k x_{i}\right)}$

Perhaps one could approximate $S(\mathbf{x})$ by defining $y\equiv \sum_{i=0}^k x_{i}$ and finding an approximation to $y-\log(y)$. Any ideas?

**Edit:** If $y_k=\sum_{i=0}^k x_i$ is a bounded sequence, can we hope to find an approximation of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{e^{y_k}}{y_k}
$$
for $x_i>0$?

Comment: Even when $(x_i)$ is a constant sequence with value $a\neq 0$, the resulting sum $$\frac{e^a}{a}+\frac{e^{2a}}{2a}+\cdots+\frac{e^{na}}{na}+\frac{e^{(n+1)a}}{(n+1)a}$$does not simply further.

Comment: @SangchulLee what if $y_k=\sum_{i=0}^k x_i$ is a bounded sequence, can we hope to find an approximation of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{e^{y_k}}{y_k}$? Added this to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment*

As noted by @SangchulLee : If $(x_i)$ is a constant sequence with value $a≠0$ , then the sum is

$$
S(a,n) = \frac{e^a}{a}+\frac{e^{2a}}{2a}+\cdots+\frac{e^{na}}{na}+\frac{e^{(n+1)a}}{(n+1)a} \tag{1}
$$

Suppose $a >0$, then

$$
S(a,n) 
= \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} \int_{-\infty}^1   e^{y k a} dy\\
= \int_{-\infty}^1 \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}  ( e^{y a})^k dy\\
= \frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^a \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}  ( e^{z})^k dz\\ 
= \frac{1}{a} \int_{-\infty}^a  \frac{e^{z} (e^{z (n + 1)} - 1)}{e^{z} - 1} dz\\
$$

Analytic solutions for this integral for fixed $n$ bring back the sum as in (1). However, the integral may be useful for finding approximations. To do so, let us factor out an even term:

$$
S(a,n) 
= \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^a  \frac{e^{z} (e^{z (n + 1)} - 1)}{e^{z} - 1} dz\\
= \frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^a  \frac{e^{z (n+2)/2} \sinh (z (n+1)/2) }{\sinh (z/2)} dz\\
= \frac{2}{a} \int_{-\infty}^{a/2}  \frac{e^{w (n+2)} \sinh (w (n+1)) }{\sinh (w)} dw
$$

Note that $\frac{\sinh (w (n+1)) }{\sinh (w)} $ is an even function of $w$ which may be used for further approximations.